# How to navigate back from programmatically opened overlay permissions screen in android?

Tags: android, react-native, permissions, overlay

How to navigate back from overlay permission screen?

I need to ask draw over other apps permission in order to show floating widget. I open overlay permission screen, but how to navigate back to app from there.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no API to navigate back programmatically. You can always try a "hacky" way like a background service that detects the permission every some time interval and, if granted, starts Activity again. But don't do that. The better way is to show a dialog with instructions on how to navigate back manually before asking for permission.